# Дженерики typescript, почему такой код выдаёт ошибку Type '{}' is not assignable to type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, объекты, generics

Никак не могу понять почему такой код выдаёт ошибку - Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Keys<T>'.

```
type Keys<T extends string|symbol>={
    [key in T]: string;
};
const foo = <T extends string|symbol>()=>{
    const a:Keys<T> = {}
    return a
}
```

Причем если подставить вручную тип string или symbol, никаких ошибок получено не будет. Лишь предупреждение о том, что T для функции объявлен, но не используется.

Пример рабочих кодов:

```
type Keys<T extends string|symbol>={
    [key in T]: string;
};
const foo = <T extends string|symbol>()=>{
    const a:Keys<string> = {}
    return a
}
```

```
type Keys<T extends string|symbol>={
    [key in T]: string;
};
const foo = <T extends string|symbol>()=>{
    const a:Keys<symbol> = {}
    return a
}
```

Вы можете проверить код [здесь](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcA8AVKEAewIDsAmCUCwATgJY4DmAPgiALYBGA9gDYB8AvAN4BQUAqAG0A1vCgUoKALoAuIqQqUA3LwC+qgMbMcxKADNmzKJyip0WXAQXkqtBiw4AKAJSd2fQVG27gUAIaycIio7CZQ3Gr8giQQwACuJDgB6rxpAPTpUsasEP5JUPTMsQEs8X7AABbQrP5U8f6UEAA03qxkmiKlzABu0JIARACiGP70YLkIA1DFUAMA6pX+wADkhAByEADuAwB0vJlQAPJVECRbZAgtUE1+xPnYeFCMIFCxRT1KUKdX3sz09FwwEIdSepygW2KrCelygIGYiSgE38IEoJAR+H2AiAA)

Comment: Ну а так например `const a: Keys<"key"> = {}`будет ошибка. Тс же не знает что в T будет.

Comment: @sailybra, могу ли я как-то сделать чтобы T был эквивалентен только типу string или типу symbol?

Answer (score 0):

`type Keys<T extends string|symbol>` - T это обобщенный тип, т.е. при использовании такого type нужно будет явно указать тип (заменить T на нужный тип данных).
Ты получаешь ошибку, т.к. используешь свой генерик c 'обобщенным' типом. И соответсвенно не получаешь ошибку, когда подставляешь `Key<string>`

Мне кажется, что по задумке, ты хотел сделать что то вроде

```
type Keys<T extends string | symbol> = Record<T, string>;

const a: Keys<symbol> = {
  [Symbol('id')] = '12345'
}
```

Или даже

```
const a: Record<symbol, string> = ....
```